# Can I add a total to the result without a subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a select statement that shows a set of totals in a table by timestamp and year/half years going back.

But I'm having trouble adding a way to show the sum total of the count of the records. Can I do it without a subquery? Or would I have to add a column to the result and make it into a running total?

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
  SUM(x) Total
FROM
(
SELECT YEAR(TimeStamp) Year, 1 + MONTH(TimeStamp) / 7 Half, count(*) ct
FROM Table1
WHERE Row1 = 'Blah'
GROUP BY YEAR(TimeStamp), 1 + MONTH(TimeStamp) / 7
ORDER BY Year DESC, Half ASC
)
 x
```

But it won't parse correctly. I'm sure there's something wrong with my syntax but I'm not sure how to get it to show a total at the bottom or anywhere, even if in the result.

I saw the question [Percent to total in PostgreSQL without subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489848/percent-to-total-in-postgresql-without-subquery) but I'm not wanting to scan the table twice and I don't understand window functions yet, but I tried and couldn't make it work here.

Comment: You can't so a sum of the entire subquery. But it is not clear to me what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Can you show what exactly you want in your result? Only the sum, a new rows with the sum or a column with the sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use grouping sets:

```
SELECT YEAR(TimeStamp) Year, 1 + MONTH(TimeStamp) / 7 Half, count(*) ct
FROM Table1
WHERE Row1 = 'Blah'
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (YEAR(TimeStamp), 1 + MONTH(TimeStamp) / 7, ())
ORDER BY Year DESC, Half ASC;
```